# Evaluating angle of refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, refraction

Can someone show me how to evaluate the angle of refraction for white light where the angle of incidence is 30 degrees if medium A is air and medium B is water. The answer is 22 degrees. I don't know how this works. What formula do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Snell's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law), which states,

$$n_1\sin \theta_1 = n_2 \sin\theta_2$$

For air, $n_1=1.000293$ and for water $n_2=1.333$. As you stated in the question, the angle of incidence is $\theta_1=30$ degrees. Therefore, the angle of refraction is given by,

$$\theta_2 = \arcsin \left( \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin\theta_1\right) = 22.09°$$

Comment: I think it isn't a good idea to post the full answer to a homework question like this. The asker stands to learn nothing (this becomes especially clear considering the even more recent duplicate he posted)...

Comment: @Danu: Your profile picture is a little odd, is it by any chance a sphere being turned 'inside out'?

Comment: Yes, I think you got that right! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morin_surface I have no clue what it *really* is: Besides being pretty it symbolizes some of the mathematics that I would *love* to learn more about. Currently applying for programs in mathematical physics so my hopes are high!

Comment: Also, as an interesting aside, note that Morin is blind! ;)